# Database design: Multiple of the same type of item

Tags: database-design

I wasn't sure entirely how to word this for the question, so I'll explain what I'm thinking. I have previous experience designing databases but really haven't decided how I want to implement this or run across this before. I'll explain what I'm thinking as a way of showing I have thought this out...

I'm creating a database that will store information of a user for things like a resume (this is a side project for a bunch of college kids). The issue I'm coming across is how to deal with storing a large amount of things like technical skills, perhaps of the order of 20+ per user as well as their proficiency

Idea one: One huge table with columns of TechSkill1 -> 20. Along with their proficiency. Use the user ID as the FK to relate to all of these.
Pros: Easiest implement, easiest on the front end.
Cons: limited to 20 skills, lots of potential for nulls, excessive size

Idea two: Table of a large text input with all skills in one text object delimited by some character like a comma or a |. Another column for proficiencies delimited the same way. Again, USERID as a FK.
Pros: easy to implement, small table size, easy on the front end to get information
Cons: possibility of wasting a lot of empty space, need to do more coding on the front end before the store and then upon retrieving.

Idea Three: Small table with the column of skill and proficiency. Then create multiple rows to relate to each USERID
Pros: smallest table and cleanest. Saves the most space
Cons: front end implementation will be interesting as in, how to deal with multiple fields for an unlimited amount of entries (not my stuff, but I don't want to create too many issues for the front end guys)

Those were my three ideas, I'm not entirely sure what would be best so... I'm asking you guys. All advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

-Jabsy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best way to implement this on database level is to create 4 tables:

- USERS (you probably have this one)
- SKILLS
- PROFICIENCIES
- SKILLS_PROFICIENCIES (fk_userid, fk_proficiencyid,fk_skill_id)

This way you won't waste space and your architecture will be more scalable and maintanable.

You addressed problem of front end implementation. The best way remedy this is create database View (which DB engine u use?) with more "front end friendly" view of data. It's not a good idea to denormalize your schema to ease up front end development, mainly because data manipulations are the most fragile operations in information systems. Keep your schema clean and you will save yourself a lot of trouble in the future when scaling up and adding new features.

Comment: So with this implementation I SQL select from my Skill_prof table based upon my user_id and then use the return from that to map to my proficiency and the corresponding skill as they will all be in the same tuple?

Edit: also, I'm using MYSQL

Comment: You can use database Join and select it by 1 query to database. For example if you want specific user and his skill names and proficiency names you will use: SELECT users.name, skills.name, prof.name from skill_prof sp inner join users us.id=fk_userid inner join skills on sp.fk_skill_id = skills.id inner join proficiencies prof on prof.id=sp.fk_proficiencyid where users.id = YOUR ID TO SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

Table 1: Contains a single column with all possible skills listed.

Table 2: Contains three columns, the userID for one column, and an associated skill for the second column. Use a compound key, the second column is limited to entries from the first table. Plus a third column with their level of ability (this might need to reference another table it depends in whether it's just a value or if it's a word). A user might have 20 different entries in thus table.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in a normalized fashion.  A `USER` table with a `USER_ID` primary key, a `SKILL` table with a `SKILL_ID` primary key, and a `USER_SKILL` table that has a `USER_ID`, a `SKILL_ID`, and a `PROFICIENCY` column.

I'm not sure that I understand whether that is what you're suggesting as the third option.  If it is, I'm not quite sure what issues you'd have with the front end.  Presumably, there will be an interface where a user adds a new skill and enters their proficiency.  That would seem to map very naturally to a properly normalized schema.

Comment: What I think I meant by the third option was having a table with 4 columns of something like table_id, skill, prof, and user_id. This way I'd do a search on the user ID and get all the information back in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

I will create 3 tables :

- `USER` table with the PK `USER_ID`
- `SKILL` table with the PK `SKILL_ID` , and a column `SKILL_DESCRITPION`
- `USER_SKILL` table with the following structure :

  - `USER_ID` , FK reference to the `USER.USER_ID`
  - `SKILL_ID`  , FK reference to the `SKILL.SKILL_ID`
  - `PROFICIENCY`

In this way , it can provides you the flexibility to include more different skill type in the future by simply inserting a new skill record in the `SKILL` table.

For how to query the result about what skills and the proficiency for each user has , you can refer to this http://bytes.com/topic/oracle/answers/64603-help-decode-function-crosstab-query if you are using oracle.Your problem description should be the same as this link described.